# Problem formatting MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, usb, install, dmg

I have two Macs, a MacBook Pro of 2006 and an iMac of 2012. The second one is used by my parents for work, the first one by me for studying.

The problem was that the laptop was okay but needed a format and so I did.

After the formatting it says, with the installation of the OS, that Mac OS X Lion 10.7.5 (last supported version for this laptop) is “At the moment not available”.

With a search on Internet, I have read that I need the installation DVD/CD (can’t find it anymore) or a bootable USB.

What I have done: I have downloaded a 10.7 Lion dmg file (don’t say that it’s piracy, I have paid the laptop!), but that it does not contains the InstallESD.dmg or SharedContent folder... Another search on the net said to me that the 10.7 Lion dmg file is the InstallESD itself (all I can say is that the file is downloaded as 10.7 Lion .dmg and after opening it is showed on the Desktop as “Mac OS X Install ESD”).

So I have prepared a USB 16GB Mac OS Journaled on my iMac of 2012 (updated to Catalina).

When I go on Disk Utility and then I click on my USB, and then I click on “Restore” and I select the InstallESD/10.7-Lion .dmg file, it starts the operation but then says:

```
Validating target
Validating source
Validating sizes - Operation not allowed
Impossible to complete (OSStatus error 1).
```

What can I do?

Comment: It's not the piracy I would worry about,  it's obtaining an operating system from an unknown source.  Always download from trusted sources.  The error you supplied could be related to it not being genuine.

Comment: I can’t find a known source and trusted source for this InstallESD for Mac OS Lion, Allan... Even on Apple Store there is no more the OS. What can I do? ...

Comment: I may have something that can assist you.  See my profile page to contact me